# Retrieve outer class as IFile from inner class identified by String

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, inner-classes

How can I retrieve the outer class from an inner class (identified by class name) for an IFile Object?

For "normal" .java classes i got something like this:

```
IFile file = project.getFile("src" + System.getProperty("file.separator")
                        + packageName
                        + System.getProperty("file.separator") + simpleClassName
                        + ".java");
```

This works obviously only for .java classes, not for inner classes.

Example:

```
public class House {

LinkedList<Room> rooms;

    public House() {
       rooms.add(new Room());
    }

   class Room {

   }
```

}

Now i want to search for "Room" and retrieve House.java.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Eclipse Java Development Tools](http://eclipse.org/jdt/). [Using the Java search engine](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_search.htm) page in Eclipse help seems to be good place to start. Using JDT implies that you have your classes in a Java project.